# Samsung Galaxy Note III emulator settings

Tags: android, android-emulator, galaxy

I am porting my iPhone app over to android and the client uses **Samsung Galaxy Note III**.

I need to create an emulator to help with the debugging, but I am getting problems in starting the emulator with the settings I got from [gsmarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_3-5665.php).

There are similar posts but they are of `Samsung Galaxy Note II` and also used old AVD.

What should be selected in AVD (**Device and Target**)?

[image]

[image]

I also did some changes and my final settings came up to be:

**Emulator AVD-**

`Device:` *1080 x 1920:xhdpi*

`Target:` *Google API's(Google Inc.) - API Level 17*

`RAM:` *256*

`VM Heap:` *48*

`Internal Storage:` *1 GB*

`SD Card Size:` *1024 MB*

With the above settings if I run the emulator, all I can see is a black blank screen even after waiting for as long as 20 minutes.

So, I checked "Run Configurations" in eclipse and there the emulator was on online mode.
Then I simply run it.

But I got the following in console:

```
[2013-10-15 15:55:15 - rabus] Android Launch!
[2013-10-15 15:55:15 - rabus] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-15 15:55:15 - rabus] Performing com.rabus.main.DispatureActivity activity launch
[2013-10-15 15:55:22 - rabus] Uploading rabus.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-10-15 15:55:48 - rabus] Installing rabus.apk...
[2013-10-15 15:55:53 - rabus] Success!
[2013-10-15 15:55:53 - rabus] Starting activity com.rabus.main.DispatureActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-10-15 15:55:58 - rabus] Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-10-15 15:55:58 - rabus] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2013-10-15 15:55:58 - rabus] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
[2013-10-15 15:55:58 - rabus] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[2013-10-15 15:56:01 - rabus] Starting activity com.rabus.main.DispatureActivity on device emulator-5554
```

As seen by the above output, the device is still not ready.

What are the correct settings for this emulator in order to get it run ?

Comment: wats the configuration of ur workstation??

Comment: @ASP - By workstation you mean: Emulator device definition like Screen Size, Sensors, Cameras, device size, Screen Ratio, Density and Device states ?

Comment: @ASP - Windows 7 ultimate, Pentium Dual Core, 3GB RAM, 32 bit Operating System.

Comment: Did you check "Use Host GPU"?

Comment: @fasteque - No, it is not marked as checked.

Comment: Enable it. Also try to reduce the ram to 512 if the results are not good.

Comment: @fasteque - As I mentioned in the question - RAM 256. So it's already reduced.

Comment: Ok cool, them try with the "Use Host GPU" enabled.

Answer (score 2):

OK after much fiddling, I got it (works as of 10/23/14)

This is for Samsung Note 3.

Create a new Device Definition.

screen size: 5.7"
 
resolution: 1080x1920
size: normal
ram: 1GB
density: XXHDPI (device is 386dpi)

No Skin (this will cause the buttons to show up, so edit the config.ini mainkeys to yes to remove them)
Then create an AVD with that, and it should match the Samsung Remote Test Labs.

Comment: update: Use Genymotion. It's quick and has built in devices such as Note 3, Nexus 6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

@user1010160: Thanks. I used your suggested settings via Android Studio and at least got an emulator to work (my original must have been incorrect). Info for others:
I could not find out how to set density to XXHDPI, so left it at default value of XHDPI.
I set the hardware keys setting to home/back/etc. I did not/have not yet set the config.ini (have not looked for it). I set the SDK level to Lollipop 5.1 (APK 22). The tutorial code that I was using with my own (bad) emulator failed with ADB errors and "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]". The tutorial now works on exactly the same code with the above emulator settings. Again, many thanks. {Background: Windows 10 x64, fully updated. I am a Flutter beginner}.

Answer (score -2):

visit this site http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action# there are various samsung emulators