# Galaxy Note 3 emulator specification

Tags: android, android-emulator

Any one please help me to create emulator for Samsung Galaxy Note 3. And will it come under large or xlarge category?

Comment: Can you please give me the reason for giving down vote for this question...

Comment: I don't have a Note3, but looking at my Note2 which is a normal-xhdpi device (like the S3) and the specs of the Note3 itself, I guess it's a normal-xxhdpi device like an S4. Look also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378446/samsung-galaxy-note-iii-emulator-settings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a Note3, but looking at my Note2 which is a normal-xhdpi device (like the S3) and the specs of the Note3 itself, I guess it's a normal-xxhdpi device like an S4.

It's confirmed by this website: http://checkscreensize.appspot.com/listdevice.jsp
search for "9005" which is one of the IDs of the Note 3.

For other details you can look at this SO question: [Samsung Galaxy Note III emulator settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378446/samsung-galaxy-note-iii-emulator-settings)

For a full list of specs: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_3-5665.php